# Filter My Array / JSON Data (including multi values) Based on Multiple Criteria in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, javascript-objects

The tricky part here is:

- Some includes more than 1 value (like active substances: ["Morphine", "Fentanyl"])
- Some values are repeating (retrospective: "1" for "true; ward_focused: "1" for true (again))

So the previous solutions here did not work for my project.

**jsonData**

```
[
 {
  "title": "Real-world evidence of high-cost drugs for metastatic melanoma",
  "url": "https://.../Suppl_1/A5.1",
  "filters": {
    "retrospective": "1",
    "ward_focused": "2",
    "indication_focused": "1",
    "active_substance": "2"
  }
 },
 {
  "title": "Real-world safety and tolerability of the recently commercialised palbociclib",
  "url": "https://.../Suppl_1/A223.2",
  "filters": {
    "retrospective": "2",
    "ward_focused": "1",
    "indication_focused": "2",
    "active_substance": "Palbociclib"
  }
 },
 {
  "title": "Cost-effectiveness of morphine versus fentanyl in managing ventilated neonates",
  "url": "https://.../Suppl_1/A7.3",
  "filters": {
    "retrospective": "1",
    "ward_focused": "1",
    "indication_focused": "1",
    "active_substance": ["Morphine", "Fentanyl"]
  }
 },
 {
  "title": "Chemical risk assessement in a quality control laboratory",
  "url": "https://.../Suppl_1/A9.2",
  "filters": {
    "retrospective": "2",
    "ward_focused": "2",
    "indication_focused": "2",
    "active_substance": "2"
  }
 },
 {
  "title": "The economic burden of metastatic breast cancer in Spain",
  "url": "https://.../27/1/19",
  "filters":{
    "retrospective": "1",
    "ward_focused": "1",
    "indication_focused": "1",
    "active_substance": "2"
  }
 }
]
```

**query**

```
const selectedFilters = {
      retrospective: ["1"],
      ward_focused: ["2"],
      indication_focused: ["1"],
      active_substance: []
  };
```

The closest solution was when I've converted my data into an array and work on it as:

```
  const filterArr = Object.values(selectedFilters).flat();

  const output = myDataArray.filter(({filters}) => {
      const objFilters = Object.values(filters).flat();
      return filterArr.every(val => objFilters.includes(val));
  })
  console.log(output);
```

BUT it failed for the reason that the "1"s "true" and the "2"s for false are repeating many times in every profile.

I'm open to work on both as JSON and array for my data. Also I may modify the "1" -"2" structure for my boolean data types. You may also change the data structure if needed by removing the “filters” detail and working on one-depth.

Any help is appreciable. Best regards

Answer (score 2):

The below snippet should filter your data using the js filter function and checking each possible filter against the filters obj

```js
const json =[
 {
  "title": "Real-world evidence of high-cost drugs for metastatic melanoma",
  "url": "https://.../Suppl_1/A5.1",
  "filters": {
    "retrospective": "1",
    "ward_focused": "2",
    "indication_focused": "1",
    "active_substance": "2"
  }
 },
 {
  "title": "Real-world safety and tolerability of the recently commercialised palbociclib",
  "url": "https://.../Suppl_1/A223.2",
  "filters": {
    "retrospective": "2",
    "ward_focused": "1",
    "indication_focused": "2",
    "active_substance": "Palbociclib"
  }
 },
 {
  "title": "Cost-effectiveness of morphine versus fentanyl in managing ventilated neonates",
  "url": "https://.../Suppl_1/A7.3",
  "filters": {
    "retrospective": "1",
    "ward_focused": "1",
    "indication_focused": "1",
    "active_substance": ["Morphine", "Fentanyl"]
  }
 },
 {
  "title": "Chemical risk assessement in a quality control laboratory",
  "url": "https://.../Suppl_1/A9.2",
  "filters": {
    "retrospective": "2",
    "ward_focused": "2",
    "indication_focused": "2",
    "active_substance": "2"
  }
 },
 {
  "title": "The economic burden of metastatic breast cancer in Spain",
  "url": "https://.../27/1/19",
  "filters":{
    "retrospective": "1",
    "ward_focused": "1",
    "indication_focused": "1",
    "active_substance": "2"
  }
 }
];
function filterJson(filterObj) {
  let hasRetrospective = false,
    hasWardFocused = false,
    hasIndicationFocused = false,
    hasActiveSubstance = false;
  const arr = json.filter(function (j) {
    hasRetrospective = filterObj.retrospective.indexOf(j.filters.retrospective) > -1;
    hasWardFocused = filterObj.ward_focused.indexOf(j.filters.ward_focused) > -1;
    hasIndicationFocused = filterObj.indication_focused.indexOf(j.filters.indication_focused) > -1;
    hasActiveSubstance = Array.isArray(j.filters.active_substance) ?    
      j.filters.active_substance.some(function (jf) {
        return filterObj.active_substance.indexOf(jf) > -1;
      }):
      filterObj.active_substance.indexOf(j.filters.active_substance) > -1;
    return hasRetrospective && hasWardFocused && hasIndicationFocused && hasActiveSubstance;
  }); 
  console.log(arr);
}
filterJson({
    retrospective: ["1"],
    ward_focused: ["1"],
    indication_focused: ["1"],
    active_substance: ["Morphine", "Fentanyl"]
});
```

Comment: thanx for the work. But what if the user did not select any active substance?? I set the filter as **active substance is empty** it looks failing for now. May you please look again?

Comment: It also did not work for the active substances e.g. ["Morphine", "Fentanyl"] or ["Fentanyl"]

Comment: 1) in the data none of your active substances are empty so  you wont get a match if the filter obj has an empty value 2) i modified active_substance to account for arrays or strings since that value is inconsistent.

Comment: you're a great contributor thank you. how can I make the necessary modification to bring all results about a specific criteria if the user does not select any option? E.g. (if the active substance section is empty, do not filter and bring all the results. It's the last step for me, thanks!

Comment: you could add a null check for each criteria so that if the filterObj.criteria is null then return true so that all results are included for that criteria.

Comment: I've got the logic, tried a few times (checked on console.log etc.) but couldn't set the ideal code. May you please make the last touch for me. You'll be my hero of the 2020!